# Is ClipIt safe? How would I test this?

Tags: security, clipboard

I have seen that [Clipit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/clipit/) has an "Offline mode", which is described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686042/clipits-offline-mode).  However, it shocked me as I thought that perhaps it was storing my data online, which would be a security concern.

Is Clipit safe to use?  How could I check that it wasn't communicating with an outside source?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/686042/clipits-offline-mode